# Using a custom ref struct enumerator in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, vectorization, ienumerator

How can I use a custom ref struct enumerator to be implicitly used in a foreach loop?

I want to be able to do something like `foreach (var el in span) {...}` using my own ref struct enumerator. The intent of this is to enumerate a span in chunks as Vector<T> instances. It was refactored from a class implementing the IEnumerator<T> interface using Memory<T> instead of Span<T> so it still follows that contract aside from the GetEnumerator and Dispose methods without actually implementing the interfaces.

I did this to guarantee no instantiation onto the heap since anybody vectorizing is in it for performance.

```cs
public ref struct VectorIterator<T> where T : struct
{
    public int Index { get; private set; }
    public int Increment { get; }
    public Span<T> VectorizedSpan { get; }

    public VectorIterator() : this(Span<T>.Empty)
    {
    }

    public VectorIterator(T[] array) : this(array.AsSpan())
    {
    }

    public VectorIterator(Span<T> span)
    {
        VectorizedSpan = span;
        Increment = Vector<T>.Count;
        Index = -Increment;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        Index += Increment;
        return Index <= VectorizedSpan.Length - Increment;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Index = -Increment;
    }

    public readonly Vector<T> Current => new Vector<T>(VectorizedSpan[Index..]);
    public readonly Span<T> Leftovers => VectorizedSpan[^(VectorizedSpan.Length % Increment)..];
}

public static class VectorIteratorHelper
{
    public static VectorIterator<T> GetVectorIterator<T>(this Span<T> span) where T : struct
        => new VectorIterator<T>(span);

    public static VectorIterator<T> GetVectorIterator<T>(this T[] array) where T : struct
        => array.AsSpan().GetVectorIterator();
}
```

I have tried to include a GetEnumerator method which did not work because Span<T> already has its own enumerator, Span<T>. Enumerator, which hides my GetEnumerator method. I'm not sure how else I could make the compiler recognize this as an enumerator like how Span<T>. Enumerator is recognized and used in for-each loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you won't be able to replace the default iterator for the type, and you'll need to do something like this:

```
foreach(var item in span.GetVectorIterator())
```

The one addition is `foreach` loops work by calling the type's `GetEnumerator()` method, however that resolves. This works even if the type does not implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator` at all, as long as an appropriate `GetEnumerator()` method exists. With that in mind, you may want to add a `GetEnumerator()` method to your custom `VectorIterator` type (it can just `return this;`).

It also means you can override the method in a derived type to replace/hide the original from the base type, but this is still only good for derived types, and won't help you with built-in types like `Span<T>`. Finally, as of C# 9 you can [tack on the `GetEnumerator()` method via an extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/extension-getenumerator), but again: it won't help you hide the original.

Finally, you may want your `VectorIterator<T>` to formally implement the [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator) and [`IEnumerator<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1) interfaces, especially as you've already done the work and only need to add the notice at the top of the struct definition.